# SIGABRT on fclose() while reading in from an image file

Tags: c, memory-management, fclose

I'm trying to read in the data from a .bmp image file so that I can manipulate it. However, after I read in the data I get two problems that I feel are related. Firstly, on the call of fclose() I get a sigabrt, and secondly, if I simply comment out the fclose() all the data I read into the structure array is set to 255 even though it was read-in correctly earlier. I'm pretty new to C so this is almost certainly rookie mistake with allocating dynamic memory.

```
Pixel** readFile(FILE* fp,Header* header,InfoHeader* infoHeader)
{

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("file not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    fread(&header->Type,SHORTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&header->Size,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&header->Reserved1,SHORTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&header->Reserved2,SHORTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&header->Offset,INTSIZE,1,fp);

    fread(&infoHeader->Size,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->Width,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->Height,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->Planes,SHORTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->Bits,SHORTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->Compression,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->ImageSize,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->xResolution,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->yResolution,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->Colors,INTSIZE,1,fp);
    fread(&infoHeader->ImportantColors,INTSIZE,1,fp);

    int rows = infoHeader->Height;
    int cols = infoHeader->Width;


    Pixel** pixelArr = malloc(rows * sizeof(Pixel*));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        pixelArr[i] = (Pixel*) malloc(sizeof(Pixel));
    }


    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {

            fread(&pixelArr[i][j].Red,CHARSIZE,1,fp);
            fread(&pixelArr[i][j].Green,CHARSIZE,1,fp);
            fread(&pixelArr[i][j].Blue,CHARSIZE,1,fp);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);


    return pixelArr;
}
```

Comment: thank you missed that small detail, that did fix the fclose() issue any idea why all the data is getting set to 255?

Comment: When you're allocating each row of pixels, you need to allocate enough space for `rows` pixels — you're only allocating enough space for one pixel per row.

Comment: thanks, I knew it was something simple I just couldn't see.